# How to Create Google Drive Activity ConsolidationStrategy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-activity, google-drive-activity-api

Using Drive Activity Api, there's an option called consolidationstrategy. I think it should act like a filter/ where clause grouping activities that are related.

I'd simply want to consolidate all activities that affect the same folder...

Just one activity when some file(s) are created in folderIDxxxxx.

I don't know which folder it will be, only that it should be in any folder inside the **ancestor**

Can someone help me construct this--> legacy": {}

```
const request = {
    pageSize: 10,
    "ancestorName": "items/1iy....PARENTFOLDER_BEING_MONITORED",
  "filter": "time >= \"TIME_TO_CHECK\" AND detail.action_detail_case:(CREATE)"
    "consolidation_strategy": { "legacy": {} },
  };
```

Or give me a way of knowing which folder (under ancestor) has had new files uploaded in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing and I was not able to modify the `legacy:{}` object as it looks like it needs to have:

> A strategy which consolidates activities using the grouping rules from the legacy V1 Activity API

However the `Activity API v1` is already deprecated so I couldn't find any grouping rule that can be used, nevertheless constructing the query as the following example should give you the details that you need of an specific folder:

```
{
  "consolidationStrategy": {
    "legacy": {}
  },
  "pageSize": 1,
  "filter": "time >= 1648668240000 AND detail.action_detail_case:(CREATE)",
  "itemName": "items/YOUR_FOLDER_ID"
}
```

The time frame I was using to test the query was after March 30th 2022 so you may want to change the time to a different value. In my scenario this query resulted in providing the newly created files on my testing folder after the date I was looking for results.

Documentation:

1. [Consolidation Strategy](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22consolidationStrategy%22%3A%7B%22legacy%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22pageSize%22%3A1%2C%22filter%22%3A%22time%20%3E%3D%201648668240000%20AND%20detail.action_detail_case%3A(CREATE)%22%2C%22itemName%22%3A%22items%2F1gjtg058iVyGKOwZNI9lp0wmuzbvwhKA5%22%7D%7D#consolidationstrategy)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I've also done further testing and come to the same conclusion: ConsolidationStrategy doesn't work, there are no fields to it. I've solved by getting the target fileID of the activity then find the parents using DriveApp

Comment: Exactly, seems like the grouping rules used by this method are no longer working as they were based on the V1 version, just a quick reminder to accept answers that help you so other users can find them.